# Why is the singleton language {x} regular?

Tags: regular-language

So in most definitions of a regular language, it states that Ø and {x} are regular. I am curious as to why the singleton language {x} is regular, like what proof or reasoning for it to be a regular language? This is important to me, because I am using the singleton to prove why other languages are regular and I would like to have a better understanding of that.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: It is just the definition.

Comment: It has a regular grammar with one production: $S\to x$

Comment: All finite languages are regular.